# Creating a custom VBA function to display Team assignments on a Service Record

Tags: vba, excel

I have a large table which contains a list of services provided by our clinicians. I also have a separate table with the clinicians name, ID number, and team assignment. The problem is that the Services table does not include a Team column, which I need.

I would like a VBA function that will look into the Services table, and based on the clinician ID, insert the Team name as a new cell on the service record.

In the past, I had used conditional formatting to accomplish this,
    =ISNUMBER(MATCH(F1,TeamAClinicians,0)).
Where F1 held the Clinician ID for the service, and TeamAClinicians is a named range of clinician IDs on the clinician/team table. I would then repeat this rule for each team, and then manually input the team after sorting the table by colors.

This is ineffective, and only works on relatively small tables. A custom VGA function, that I could then copy down the table in it's own column would be invaluable.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:
As pointed out below, VLOOKUP was the way to go. I ended up using a very simple line: 
    =vlookup(F1,ClinicianTable,3,FALSE)
Where F1 was the cell containing the staff ID, ClinicianTable was the named table containing Team assignments.

Comment: Any sample data to work on ? (But I would better use something like VLOOKUP() on based on the clinician name.

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is all HIPAA protected.

Comment: Make a sample with dummy data, sounds not that hard to create a 10 lines fake list and a 10 lines fake clinicians mimicking the layout of your real data. By the way, did you had a look at VLOOKUP ?

Comment: I had played with VLookup before, but I am quite new to this. Could you give me a description of what VLOOKUP would do in this case?

Comment: How do I share the mock up data?

Comment: See [this example](http://www.excelfunctions.net/Vlookup-Example-Exact-Match.html) which seems matching exactly your need (with different names)

Comment: Edit your question and  copy paste your table, then select it and press the button with {} to format as `code` (or press ctrl+k) it will give a representation in fixed font with correct spacing.

Comment: All it took was a little push in the right direction. I've edited my post to include the VLOOKUP formula. I knew it had to be something simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do using excel VBA you may try the code given below.
Illustrative sample sheets are appended below.
You can modify the program to your exact situation.
[image: sheet which contains team data]
[image: sheet where team data is to be updated after program run]

Try this code:

```
 Sub Test()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, colStatus As Long, lastrowplus As Long, lastrowminus As Long

    colStatus = 3 'your status column number
    lastrowplus = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(Sheets("Sheet1").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    lastrowminus = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(Sheets("Sheet2").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lastrowplus
        For j = 1 To lastrowminus
            If Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 1).Value = Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, 1).Value Then
                Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(j, colStatus).Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, colStatus).Value
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```